# Calculated column formula help

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a request to generate a tracker number when a new item is created to a list based on the below logic:

1. The number format is "TN" + CurrentDate(ddMonYY format) + Counter. eg: TN18Oct2101
2. The counter increments for that day for all tasks created. The counter will be reset on everyday. For eg: TN18Oct2101, TN18Oct2102,...Then TN19Oct2101

Can this be achieved through a calculated column?

Thanks
Venkat

Comment: This is achievable using calculated column only if you enter the "Counter" manually from list forms.

Comment: This isn't possible from a calculated column as you cannot reference other rows (to know what the counter value should be). Best bet would be to solve this using Power Automate with a flow that runs on item creation and first does a query of entries with a Created date of today and uses the count of results to determine the counter value. However, depending on how fast items are being added there is the potential for a concurrency issue that may need to be accounted for.

Answer (score 0):

**Please following steps:**

1.Create a Single line of text column named "**Counter**"

[image]

2.Create the first **Calculated column** named "Current Date"

**Formula:**

```
=TEXT(TODAY(),"ddmmmyyyy")
```

[image]

3.Create the second **Calculated column** named "Tracker number"

**Formula:**

```
=CONCATENATE("TN",[Current Date],[Counter])
```

[image]

[image]

4.If you don’t want to show "**Current Date**" column, you can choose to hide it

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can the counter column be a calculated column and it auto increments by itself on every record got added? Also the counter needs to be reset and starts from "1" on every day like i mentioned in my question 2.

Comment: Hi user2459457. The calculated column does not auto increments by itself, it is combined according to the value in the [Counter]. Note: The value in [Counter] is manually entered by me.